# PHP: combine two queries into one or two query results into a single array?

Tags: php, arrays, inner-join

Is it possible to do a single query and retrieve values from TWO tables, like the following pseudo-code?

```
SELECT table1.Key, table2.Id
 FROM table1, table2
 INNER JOIN table2
 ON table1.text=table2.text AND table1.amount = table2.amount
WHERE …
```

If not, what I basically need to do is two consecutive queries on the tables and then combine the results into ONE (json_encoded) array, such that

Array 1 (first query): `[{"Key":"63058"},{"Key":"63059"},…`

Array 2 (second query): `[{"id":"1010","amount":"5820"},{"id":"1011","amount":"6820"}, …`

becomes

`[{"Key":"63058", "id":"1010","amount":"5820"},{"Key":"63059", "id":"1011","amount":"6820"}, …`

What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't list `table2` twice. It should just be in the `JOIN` clause, not also the `FROM` clause. Otherwise, your query is correct -- that's the normal way to join two (or more) tables and return values from both of them. So it should be:

```
SELECT table1.Key, table2.Id
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.text=table2.text AND table1.amount = table2.amount
WHERE …
```